# How to include foreach statement inside heredoc EOM

Tags: laravel-4, foreach, tcpdf, heredoc

I use EOM inside laravel controller to write html code and then pass it to a PDF class called TCPDF, the reason I'm doing this is because TCPDF doesn't load views, that's why I have to write html and css inside my controller.

Everything worked fine until I had to insert a foreach statement inside EOM to load a table for each $user, the code looks like this

```
$tbl= <<<EOM
 <table>
    <tr>
            <td>
              {$user['name']}
             </td>
           <td>
              {$user['age']}
             </td>
            </tr>
</table>
EOM;
```

And I want to do something like:

```
$tbl= <<<EOM
foreach($users as $user){
 <table>
        <tr>
                <td>
                  {$user['name']}
                 </td>
               <td>
                  {$user['age']}
                 </td>
                </tr>
    </table>
}
```

EOM;
Please tell me how if you know

Answer (score 0):

i have no expireince with EOM in laravel
but i guess you have to try 
@foreach 
@endforeach

as we have used in blades

i am not sure about it , so best of luck

Answer (score 0):

After doing lots of searches and digging into the problem, plus nobody here was able to solve this problem which I called naive by both TCPDF package and also heredoc, I FINALLY found a solution after two days of attempts. The solution doesn't include heredoc (EOM), rather is basically to concatenate the variable $tbl with html attributes inside foreach loop like this:

```
 $tbl='<table>';

    foreach($users as $key => $user) {

        $html .= '<tr><td>' . $user['name'] . '</td>
    <td>' . $user['age'] . '</td></tr>';
    }
    $tbl .= '</table>';
```